# How to hide browse/page/share ribbon for specific users?

Tags: 2013, ribbon

How can I remove this ribbon:
[image]

for specific users which has only read permissions?

Comment: Why would you remove it?

Comment: Because I'm required to, also it some users don't need this at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use JS library SPServices from codeplex to get current user permissions: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser

And then just hide the menu item with JS. The hardest part is to obtain the permissions, which can be done smoothly with SPServices.

You can add this JS to edited master page, or develop custom control, maybe just add web part to specific pages, where you want to hide the ribbon.

To avoid "flashing" of the ribbon maybe hide it first by CSS for everyone and then just display for the persons with specific permissions.

Comment: Keep in mind that this approach only hides it client side, so if you need to hide it for security reasons, this is not secure enough. But for just "cleaning" the GUI from unnecessary objects, this works great

Comment: There is no security issue because all the controls inside the ribbon are handled by default. So only "security" reason I can think of is they do not want users to know the path to the site/list.

Comment: Well security is a wide term, not wanting users to access certain paths is surely included in the term. Also, since this bar is customizable, there could be other security concerns

Comment: @luccio That's assuming permissions are properly set. If not, hiding the ribbon via client side code is merely security by obfuscation, which may be what Robert is getting at.

Comment: I agree with you, this approach should not be selected to handle security. However, my guess is, that he just wants to hide these tabs for the users who will not use it anyway (read permissions).